# How to get sticky notes attached to pdf documents while using pdf2htmlEx tool?

Tags: pdf2htmlex

Used the option **--process-annotation 1** to view annotations in pdf documents

***This works fine for***

- Highlight
- Underline
- Strikethrough
- Rectangular box

***And not for***

- **Notes** added in **Sticky notes** - the converted html contains only note icon - missing text/comment added to note icon.

Have I left out something? Or is this an issue? 
Someone kindly help me to sort this out.